# referencing an array element directly from array returning function (php)

Tags: php, arrays

```
return array(
    'client_id' => $client[0]->getId(),
    'client secret' =>  $client[0]->getSecret(),
    'redirect_uri' =>  ($client[0]->GetClientEndpoints())[0]->getRedirectUri(),
    'name' =>  $client[0]->getName());
```

specifically the snippet:

```
($client[0]->GetClientEndpoints())[0]->getRedirectUri()
```

Is there a way I can do this without having to do this:

```
 $endpoints = $client[0]->GetClientEndpoints();
 return array(
    'client_id' => $client[0]->getId(),
    'client secret' =>  $client[0]->getSecret(),
    'redirect_uri' =>  $endpoints[0]->getRedirectUri(),
    'name' =>  $client[0]->getName());
```

Comment: This syntax was adding in PHP 5.4 (I believe it was 5.4). So, use PHP >= 5.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$client[0]->GetClientEndpoints()[0]->getRedirectUri()` should work in PHP 5.4. Don't have 5.4 yet? You need to update.

It is very ugly though, and not more readable. I would:

```
$client = $client[0];
$endpoint = $client->GetClientEndpoints()[0];
return array(....
```

Comment: This is what I used, I sometimes forget the importance of readability

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it will work, but maybe you can try

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

```
return array(
    'client_id' => $client[0]->getId(),
    'client secret' =>  $client[0]->getSecret(),
    'redirect_uri' =>  array_shift($client[0]->GetClientEndpoints())->getRedirectUri(),
    'name' =>  $client[0]->getName());
```

At least this snippet works without any errors:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class class1{
    public function getRedirectUri()
    {
        return 'something';
    }
}

$arr1 = array(new class1(), new class1());

$arr = array(
    'client_id' => 'something',
    'client secret' =>  'something',
    'redirect_uri' =>  array_shift($arr1)->getRedirectUri(),
    'name' =>  'something');
```

**UPDATE** (thanks [Rudie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247372/rudie))

As it turns out, the sample above is not identical to the case of the author, so a better example (which throws E_STRICT and therefore my answer should not be considered) is:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class class2{
    public function getRedirectUri()
    {
        return 'something';
    }
}

class class1 {
    public function getArrays() {
        return array(new class2(), new class2());
    }
}
$var = new class1 ();

$arr = array(
    'client_id' => 'something',
    'client secret' =>  'something',
    'redirect_uri' =>  array_shift($var->getArrays())->getRedirectUri(),
    'name' =>  'something');
```

Comment: `array_shift` expects a reference (with `&`, you know), not a function result. This will produce a warning or notice.

Comment: hm, see above, I turned error_reporting = E_ALL and nothing with the sample above

Comment: oh, sorry, my bad, it's not identical to the authors question

Comment: yep, it throws E_STRICT with this, sorry

Comment: Nice test case! E_STRICT it is. For the perfectionists.